# Dgrid tree adding html tooltip to each cell

Tags: tree, dojo, dgrid

New to dojo and dgrid. I have a dgrid tree used in my code and would like to display the tooltip for each cell in the dgrid.

I have tried adding a formatter to the tree, however it breaks the tree. Below is sample code with formatter

```
this.OneGrid = new OneGridMixin({
            columns:{
                fieldname : tree({field:"name", width: "auto", sortable: false, formatter: function(data){return "<span title="+data+">"+data+"</span>";}})
            },  
            showHeader: false,
            minRowsPerPage: 25000,
            maxRowsPerPage: 25000
        }, "options_OneGrid");
```

I also tried adding a `title:"Title",` to the object, but it did not work. I am not sure what other parameters can the grid function accept.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following jsfiddle [dijit.Tree](http://jsfiddle.net/wuhi/5QcFY/) implementation including a tooltip:

```
 var treeControl = new dijit.Tree({
        model: treeModel,
        showRoot: false,
        _createTreeNode: function( /*Object*/
        args) {
            var tnode = new dijit._TreeNode(args);
            tnode.labelNode.innerHTML = args.label;
            return tnode;
        },
        onMouseOver: function(event) {
            var node = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(event.target);

            dijit.showTooltip("Tooltip for: " + this.model.store.getValue(node.item, "label"), node.labelNode);
        }
    }, "treeOne");
```

I don't know the `dgrid tree`, however i hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mouseover and mouseout events to show the tooltip in the dgrid.

```
this.toolTipGrid.on(".dgrid-cell:mouseover", lang.hitch(this, this.showGridTooltip));
this.toolTipGrid.on(".dgrid-cell:mouseout", lang.hitch(this, this.hideGridTooltip)); 

showGridTooltip: function(event){
    var cell=this.toolTipGrid.cell(event);
    var toolTipText="Tooltip text will go here";
    dijit.showTooltip(toolTipText, cell.element);
},

hideGridTooltip: function(event){
    var cell=this.batchStatusGrid.cell(event);
    dijit.hideTooltip(cell.element);
},
```